# 20,000 letter long dictionary in one line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, long-integer

do you have any experience with such a long dictionaries in one line 20.000? I am working on a module that has such. First I imported this dictionary with json, but I feel like it's better to import as least as possible. The code is not meant to be ever opened by the users and is working well for now. **Do you have any experience with line that has 20.000 characters?** can it cause any problems in the future?
Thanks

Comment: 20k characters long I presume? That's nothing, The real question is what are you trying to achieve, what's the purpose and if you can store it in other way that may be more suitable(database for instance).

Comment: are you getting any errors? it's not exactly clear what you're asking, are you able to provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Do you mean a={key:'val...20,000...ue'}  or a={k1:val1, k2:val2, k19999:val19999}? The second is ok, the first seems like an invitation to refactor. I have used tmp = [line.strip() for line in open(inFile)] for files with far more the 20000 lines with no problem.

Comment: I am not getting any error and yes it is the second one. {1:1,2:2,3:3....20000:20000}.. it's just seems a bit suspicous but it's working. I just wanted to know if there's a trick that in some cases it wouldn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One practical problem you could run into is `LINE_MAX`.  On *nix systems, that's the maximum length of a line which is guaranteed to be supported by all the usual utilities like `grep` and so on.  The value promised by POSIX is 2048 bytes, but some systems have a larger value like 4096.

So, if you do decide to have 20,000 characters on a single line, you can't expect the usual utility programs to be able to operate on that file.

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Utility-Minimums.html

Comment: I don't think the GNU utils still have this limitation.  I just tried grep on a file with 2GB lines, and it happily finds patterns in the middle of these lines.

Comment: At least for grep, this is [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html): "Though grep expects to do the matching on text, it has no limits on input line length other than available memory, and it can match arbitrary characters within a line."